# php sort time always give current data without formating given date

Tags: php

I have date  14.10.13 format it comes from my database table.I want to format it .but it give always today dates.I want to change it as following.

```
 04 December 2014
```

for this i use flowing code

```
 <?php  echo date("d F Y", strtotime('14.10.13'));?>
```

but it always give current date 
`04 December 2014`
format

i cannot understand what is problem.

Comment: If you have lower version of PHP in your Server you can't  DateTime::createFromFormat, so you can use str_replace(".","-",$date);  If you stored date with '.' seperation

Comment: FYI, your input string was being recognised as a time, not a date (`echo date("d F Y H:i:s", strtotime('14.10.13')); // output: 04 December 2014 14:10:13`)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Pass standard format in `date()`

```
<?php  echo date("d F Y", strtotime('14-10-13'));?>
```

using `.` is not date standard so use `-` separated date

or by replaceing

```
<?php  echo date("d F Y", strtotime(str_replace('.', '-','14.10.13')));?>
```

Comment: that date come from db 14.10.13 format can i esily replace . to - for use this

Comment: yeah you can replace with -

Answer (score 4):

If you have a known format then you can avoid the *strtotime-magic* by using [`::createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/datetime.createfromformat.php)

```
$input  = '14.10.13';
$output = DateTime::createFromFormat('y.m.d', $input)->format('d F Y');

var_dump($output);
```

Answer (score 2):

It's very simple

1. First you must store date in mysql in a 'date' datatype.
2. It stores in YYYY-MM-DD.
3. using `DATE_FORMAT(`column_name`,'%d.%m.%Y')` mysql query to fetch your date which is already inserted.

That's all. don't complicate it.

Answer (score 0):

An excerpt from the official [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) of `strtotime()`:

> **Note:**
>
> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at
>   the separator between the various components: if the separator is a
>   slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the
>   separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format
>   is assumed.
>
> To avoid potential ambiguity, it's best to use ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DD)
>   dates or DateTime::createFromFormat() when possible.

I'll go for `DateTime::createFromFormat()`.